# Error with .htaccess mod-rewrite

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I get error `500 Internal Server Error` when using the below lines in `.htaccess` file in the main directory of the website.

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^ar/?$ index.php?lan=ar [L]
RewriteRule ^en/?$ index.php?lan=en [L]
```

My intention is load `website.com/index.php?lan=en` when entering `website.com/en`. What could be the issue here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you check if the mod_rewrite is enabled on your apache server ?

If you are on Windows, check the httpd.conf file inside the apache/conf directory on your web server.

On linux like Debian / Ubuntu, check if there is the file rewrite.so in /etc/apache2/mod-enabled/ directory. Otherwise, add the module with the command `a2enmod rewrite && service apache2 restart`

Comment: How can I check this?

Answer (score 0):

I am also not seeing an issue here might be some other rule or conflicting `htaccess`, but you can do that easily by,

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^([\w-]+)/?$ index.php?lan=$1 [QSA,L]
```

Comment: After enabling `mod_rewrite`, my `.htaccess` lines are working perfectly.